# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '98.97%' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar

Here is my report. The line for set `@percent` is the issue and is returning the following error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '98.97%' to data type int.

Code:

```
declare @compliant      int
declare @notcompliant   int
declare @total          int
declare @percent        int

set @compliant = (select [# of patches] from vpatchcompliancecount where Status = 'compliant')

set @notcompliant = (select [# of patches] from vpatchcompliancecount where Status = 'not compliant')

set @total = (select SUM([# of Patches]) from vpatchcompliancecount)

set @percent = CONVERT(varchar,convert(DECIMAL (4,2),100.0 * 
(select [# of Patches] from vpatchcompliancecount where Status = 'compliant')/(select SUM([# of Patches]) from vpatchcompliancecount))) + '%'

select @compliant [Installed Patches], @notcompliant [Pending], @total [Total], @percent [Compliance %]
```

Answer (score 2):

The data type int can only contain whole numbers. Converting '98' to int would work, but '98.97' does not work. You should declare your `@Percent` variable as a `Decimal` or `Number` data type.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is wrong, it should be:

```
DECLARE    @percent    VARCHAR
```

Though personally I'd use a group by, and calculate the results as follows (this has not been error/syntax checked):

```
SELECT
    [Installed Patches] = SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'compliant' THEN [# of patches] ELSE 0 END)
    ,[Pending] = SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'not compliant' THEN [# of patches] ELSE 0 END)
    ,[Total] = SUM[# of Patches]
    ,[Compliance %] = CONVERT(VARCHAR,
        (   100.0 * 
            (   SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'compliant' THEN [# of patches] ELSE 0 END))
                / (SUM([# of patches]) 
            )
        )
    ) + '%'
FROM 
    vpatchcompliancecount
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set 98.97% to an integer.  Integers only store whole numbers.  98 would be an integer.  You would need to put the percentage into a varchar in order to include the percent sign.